# Populating an array in descending order c++ NOT sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, populate, iota

I'm trying to generate an an array in descending order, as in actually fill it from scratch. I am not trying to sort given numbers. I wanted to know if there is a way to do it without a for loop. I was able to generate an array in ascending order  of number using std::iota, but I haven't been able to (nor do I think I can) use that for generating a descending array. Is there a one liner out there for generating a array of size in descending order?

**EDIT**:
I was able to create an array in ascending order using:

```
    void generateAscendingArray(int values[], size_t size){
        std::iota(values, values+size, 1);
    }
```

So it fills the array with numbers corresponding to the size of the array. I am simply looking for an easy way to generate a descending array without a loop, or with minimal lines and work, similar to ascending. I want it to fill the array in accordance to the size of the array just in descending order.

Comment: This is a classic example of an underspecified question.  Are the array bounds dynamic or fixed?  Does a vector countnas an array?  Does a while loop count as a for loop?  What are the criteria for "success"?  While I appreciate the motivation written in English, this question may become much improved if you provide your best attempt and explain why *exactly* it is inadequit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution may be to use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) but to fill your array from back to front. Use [`std::rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and [`std::rend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend) to get reverse iterators that iterate in reverse order :

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> my_data;
    std::iota(std::rbegin(my_data), std::rend(my_data), 0);
    for (auto value : my_data) {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output :

> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Edit : It seems you are using a pointer to the first element of an array and a size instead of using a proper container object. In that case, `std::rbegin` and `std::rend` cannot deduce the size of the pointed array using the pointer alone. You will need to construct your reverse iterators manually as is done in `foo` in the following example :

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

void foo(int * data, size_t size) {
    std::reverse_iterator<int*> first(data + size);
    std::reverse_iterator<int*> last(data);
    std::iota(first, last, 0);
}

int main()
{
    int my_data[10];

    foo(my_data, sizeof(my_data) / sizeof(*my_data));

    for (auto value : my_data) {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, you would be better off ditching arrays as containers in favor of standard containers like `std::vector` or using iterators to express ranges of elements.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i want to do. But for some reason i get the error: "no matching function for call to 'rend' ". Do have an idea as to why?

Comment: @Jade Updated. The solution is less elegant when used with a `int[]` function argument. Pointer/size pairs works as a way of expressing a range of elements but it's not a very good way of doing it. This is one example of the approach's shortcomings.